# Select rows by one field and sort by another across multiple tables with mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 7 different tables that all have the same field, `user`(int) and `time`(int). Ideally, I want one query that will select all the rows that match a specific user, then sort them all by time. 
I've tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp (JOIN FULL) with no success. I'm having a hard time searching because I don't even know if a JOIN is what I need here.

Something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table1,table2,table3 WHERE user='1' ORDER BY time DESC`

Would get me this:

```
//my query and a while loop here
    $row['food'];//[{"food" : "burrito","qty" : "1" }]
    $row['feel'];//8
    //next row
    $row['ailment'];// xx some value xx
    $row['feel'];//4
    //etc
```

Here's some examples of the tables - I have a users table too.

```
+----+------------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| id | time       | ailments         | user | feel | comment |
+----+------------+------------------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | 1426870546 | xx some value xx | 1    |    4 |         |
|  2 | 1426870577 | xx some value xx | 1    |    4 |         |
|  3 | 1426870881 | xx some value xx | 1    |    8 |         |
|  4 | 1426877198 | xx some value xx | 5    |    8 |         |
|  5 | 1426881122 | xx some value xx | 2    |    2 |         |
|  6 | 1426881778 | xx some value xx | 6    |    8 |         |
+----+------------+------------------+------+------+---------+
```

and

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+------+------+---------+
| id | time       | food                                | user | feel | comment |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | 1426860681 | [{"food" : "burrito","qty" : "1" }] | 2    |    8 |         |
|  2 | 1426861024 | [{"food" : "burrito","qty" : "1" }] | 1    |    8 |         |
|  3 | 1426861043 | [{"food" : "burrito","qty" : "1" }] | 5    |    8 |         |
|  4 | 1426861069 | [{"food" : "burrito","qty" : "1" }] | 2    |    8 |         |
|  5 | 1426882559 | [{"food" : "taco","qty" : "1" }]    | 6    |    7 |         |
|  6 | 1426884089 | [{"food" : "taco","qty" : "1" }]    | 6    |    7 |         |
|  7 | 1426884487 | [{"food" : "taco","qty" : "1" }]    | 6    |    7 |         |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+------+------+---------+
```

EDIT: Users table, the `user` in the other table is the `id` in this one

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | user |  pass  | email  |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | jim  | xxxxx  | j@b.ca |
|  4 | otto | xxxxx  | o@b.ca |
|  5 | tat  | xxxxx  | t@b.ca |
|  6 | al   | xxxxx  | a@b.ca |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Apart from each of the tables having a `user` column, is there any other direct relationship between the tables? If you were to join the 2 tables above you would have 3 rows for `user=1` with the "1 burrito" being repeated 3 times - I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Comment: @PeterBowers I have a users table which lists all the users, I'll add that to my question, maybe that'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that each table follows the same pattern as the 2 that you've shown us: id, time, user, feel, comment, plus 1 otherwise-named column (food and ailments in these cases). To be clear I will name the other columns A, B, etc.  I will name each table after it's "special" column. (Next time give us some table names...)

```
SELECT id, time, ailments AS special, user, feel, comment, 'ailments' as src
FROM table_ailments
WHERE user = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, time, food as special, user, feel, comment, 'food' as src
FROM table_food
WHERE user = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, time, A as special, user, feel, comment, 'A' as src
FROM table_A
WHERE user = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, time, B as special, user, feel, comment, 'B' as src
FROM table_B
WHERE user = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, time, C as special, user, feel, comment, 'C' as src
FROM table_C
WHERE user = 1
ORDER by user, time
```

This will give you all rows from all tables ordered by user and then by time and you can tell where the row came from by looking at the `src` column

Comment: What does `ailments AS special` and `'ailments' as src` do?

Comment: It gives an alias to that column. Since ailments and food and A and B and C will all be in the same column I renamed it to be "special" rather than having to refer to "food" as "ailments".  Same thing with the last column which I have made a string indicating what type of record it is (what 'source' the record comes from).

Comment: Sometimes I have more than one 'special' could that be written as: `..id, time, food as special, drink as special1, user...`?

Comment: Sure, but in all the rest except that particular table you will need to say `...id, time, ailments as special, '' as special1, user...` - you have to put an empty string or null or something as a placeholder so you have the same number of columns in each section of the union.

Comment: RE:  `ORDER by user, time` if I'm only selecting one user, why would I have to ORDER by user too? The rest of it worked, you're a wizard for sure.

Comment: First time I put it in I missed that you were selecting on a single user. When I put in the `where user = 1` I forgot to remove this column in the `order by`. You are right - it is not needed.